# Nomenclatura de tabela e coluna

Tags: sql, tabela-banco-de-dados, convenções-de-nome

Há pelo menos uns quatro anos eu trabalho com a seguinte nomenclatura de tabelas e colunas que é exatamente dessa forma: O nome da coluna sempre será **nome_da_tabela** + **nome_da_coluna** = 
**nome_da_tabela_nome_da_coluna**, abaixo, exemplifiquei:

- tabela `usuario`

  - **colunas**
  - `usuario_id`,`usuario_nome`,`usuario_ativo`,`...`
- tabela `cliente`

  - **colunas**
  - `cliente_id`,`cliente_nome`,`cliente_ativo`,`...`
- tabela `cliente_endereco`

  - **colunas**
  - `cliente_endereco_id`,`cliente_endereco_cliente_id`,`cliente_endereco_cep`,`cliente_endereco_logradouro`,`...`
- tabela `pedido`

  - **colunas**
  - `pedido_id`,`pedido_empresa_id`,`pedido_cliente_id`,`...`
- tabela `motivo_cancelamento`

  - **colunas**
  - `motivo_cancelamento_id`,`motivo_cancelamento_nome`,`motivo_cancelamento_ativo`,`...`
- tabela `pedido_motivo_cancelamento`

  - **colunas**
  - `pedido_motivo_cancelamento_pedido_id`,`pedido_motivo_cancelamento_motivo_cancelamento_id`,`pedido_motivo_cancelamento_ativo`

Obs.: Jamais misturo inglês com português, o que faz com que alguns nomes realmente fiquem grandes.

Eu como desenvolvedor e como usuário da rede, não abrevio e não gosto de abreviação, sofro com isso e já sofri muito no desenvolvimento onde eu não sabia o nome real das tabelas, colunas e até mesmo variáveis por estarem abreviados e acontece que eu não sei responder para quem me pergunta se esse meu padrão é "certo" ou "não é certo", logo, esse *"padrão"* intitulado como *"meu"* de nomenclatura que apresentei acima é ou **pode ser considerado errado** e que fará com que outros desenvolvedores tenham problemas com isso? Ou é apenas errado e não fará com que outros desenvolvedores tenham problemas com isso? Ou talvez uma pergunta melhor: como eu poderia melhorar isso?

Comment: São duas respostas sobre sql, vale apena dar uma olhada. [Worst coding standard you've ever had to follow?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/19070/106391)

[What was the strangest coding standard rule that you were forced to follow?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/218842/1342547).

Comment: Dê uma olhada na minha resposta, por favor, pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Resposta curta e direta

Resumindo, você pode criar o padrão que bem entender desde que esteja bem documentado e que seja internacionalizado.

Portanto, pode dizer que está errado quando:

- Não possui documentação adequada (óbvio né).

- Não possui padrão internacionalizado. (ainda uma questão polêmica, infelizmente)

<sub>Resposta detalhada, com exemplos, estudo de casos, etc, segue leitura abaixo:</sub>

Não há uma regra que diz se é certo ou errado.

Cada um decide um padrão que desejar. Obviamente, se o padrão estiver bem documentado, não tem problema.

## Redundância

Particularmente, o exemplo que postou na pergunta eu não gosto pois é redundante ter o nome da tabela nas colunas dentro da tabela. Mas é um gosto pessoal meu. Claro que se eu pegar um projeto com um padrão desse tipo, não vou ficar chorando.. rsrs Como profissional, tolero, respeito e cumpro com o dever. Mas se pego um projeto do ZERO, prefiro usar um padrão sem nomenclaturas redundantes.

Exemplo de redundância:

```
tabela1
   tabela1_coluna1
   tabela1_coluna2
   tabela1_coluna3
```

É redundante e torna o nome muito extenso.

Isso aqui é suficiente:

```
tabela1
   coluna1
   coluna2
   coluna3
```

Pelo menos esse é o padrão que normalmente uso.

Quando preciso referenciar uma tabela com outra, aí sim, descrevo o nome da tabela

```
tabela1
   id
   foo
   bar

tabela2
   id
   tabela1_id
   outra_coluna
   outra_coluna2
```

Nesse exemplo na "tabela2", a coluna "tabela1_id" faz referência a coluna "id" da tabela "tabela1".

A coisa complica quando uma tabela tem um nome um pouco mais extenso.

Exemplo "tabela_com_nome_maior"

Se coincidir de existir uma coluna com nome extenso, "coluna_com_nome_grande", o resultado seria "tabela_com_nome_maior_coluna_com_nome_grande". Enfim, não é errado, mas é horrível. E ainda pode ter problemas com sistemas que não permitem nomes muito extensos.

Para evitar isso sempre procuro nomear com nomes mais resumidos possível.

## Padrão com letras iniciais

No Brasil tem um "padrão" que consiste em usar somente as letras iniciais.

<sub>Note que "padrão" está entre aspas, ok?</sub>

Exemplo de como eu faria para uma tabela de clientes e endereços desses clientes:

```
clientes
   id
   nome
   blablabla

clientes_enderecos
   id
   clientes_id
   cep
   bairro
   blabla
```

Agora, traduzindo a mesma estrutura para um "padrão" muito usado no Brasil, conforme citei acima, o padrão consiste em usar somente as iniciais.

```
c
   id
   nome
   blablabla

c_e
   id
   c_id
   cep
   bairro
   blabla
```

Lembro que quando comecei a programar por volta de 1998, num curso de delphi o professor ensinava com esse padrão usando somente as iniciais. O tempo passou e não lembrava e nunca usei assim, mas recentemente conheci uma pessoa que usa esse padrão e lembrei dessa coisa de 20 anos atrás.

Não sei como está no Brasil, se tem outros padrões, etc, mas parece que esse padrão com letras iniciais ainda existe provavelmente porque é lecionado em cursos como o que eu fiz em 1998.

Esse padrão é bacana pelo fato de que mesmo uma tabela com nome extenso fica bastante curto. O problema é que sempre terá um trabalho a mais em consultar a documentação para somente saber o que significa o nome de uma tabela, caso não lembre. É um incômodo pequeno, mas ainda assim é um incômodo. As vezes você está no gás total super concentrado então tem que parar para ler a documentação para entender que merd** quer dizer `c_o_i_o`, por exemplo. Se a tabela tiver um nome intuitivo, você não precisa parar e perder a concentração. Mas enfim, é apenas um exemplo pequeno e tolerável.

O ponto mais “falho” nesse padrão é a colisão de nomes. Num projeto pequeno dificilmente colidirá nomes mas uma situação desse tipo pode ser comum. Exemplo ilustrativo: `customer_duplicated` e `customer_deleted` seria `c_d`. Teria que mudar um ou outro. Então “deleted” pode mudar para "excluded". Mas caso já exista uma tabela "c_e", terá que usar a criatividade sem destoar do significado original “deleted”. Uma nova opção poderia ser “archived”. Ficaria “c_a”. Mas, e se já existir “c_a”?

É uma limitação simples que causa uma complicação enorme. Você perde tempo enrolado numa coisa tão pequena que poderia estar resolvida com outro padrão mais adequado. No final das contas provavelmente resolveria nas pressas colocando um número “c_d2”. Destoa do padrão do projeto e dá início a uma série de gambiarras. Afinal, uma contravenção “aqui” pode ser feita “ali” também.

## Internacionalização

Antes de começar, vou citar um caso para que entenda a importância de um padrão internacionalizado.

Mudando para outro lado do mundo, no Japão, já lidei com uma empresa onde o programador é um ultra-nacionalista. Esses tipos odeiam qualquer coisa que não seja nacional. No padrão do banco de dados, os nomes das tabelas e colunas estavam todos em ideogramas kanjis. O cara evitava até mesmo o [hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana),  [katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana) ou a transliteração em [romaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese). Para piorar, usava termos que não encontra-se facilmente em dicionários. Inclusive, o projeto inicial era para usar POSTGRE ou MySQL, mas ambos não suportavam nomes de tabelas e colunas em multibyte. A brilhante solução para manter a pose de nacionalista foi optar pelo Oracle. Forçou a empresa a pagar licensas, modificar os códigos dos programas e ainda ter mais um custo com profissional certificado Oracle. Nada contra Oracle, mas foi uma situação extremamente ridícula e desnecessária pois não usa nem 5% do potencial do SGDB.

Como se isso não bastasse, foi bastante complicado ter que ler e traduzir as 300 tabelas, cada uma com mais de 20 colunas. Tudo em kanji, dos mais cabulosos que existe.. rsrs. Até mesmo os meus colegas japoneses na época tinham dificuldade em entender os nomes.

Por fim, uma criancice que custou caro para a empresa. Obviamente quem pagou foi o cliente que encomendou o serviço. E paga até hoje. rsrs.

Para evitar situações como essa, no mínimo, deve ter um padrão internacionalizado. O idioma para internacionalização é o inglês.

O mesmo vale para um brasileiro ou qualquer outra nacionalidade. Um dia a sua empresa pode contratar um americano, um indiano, um russo, vietnamita, expandir serviços para outro país, enfim. Pessoas de qualquer parte do planeta sabe se virar com inglês com facilidade. Se o aplicativo não for internacionalizado, terá mais custos pois o programador perderá tempo em traduzir e entender a estrutura e, ainda com riscos de entender errado. Lembrando também que obviamente isso é válido para a documentação e não somente para códigos, nomes de tabelas, nomes de funções, etc.

## Nomes reservados

É recomendável evitar nomes reservados como `date`, `data`, `name`, dentre outros que variam de acordo com o SGBD.

No entanto, isso vem mudando recentemente. Atualmente os SGDBs permitem usar o nome "que quiser", mas alguns ainda podem apresentar conflitos com nomes reservados caso não sejam escapados para uma interpretação literal.

Exemplo com MySQL

```
tabela
   id
   date
   bla_bla_bla
```

Pode ocorrer problemas num SELECT, por exemplo

```
SELECT id, date FROM tabela
```

Para evitar problemas, basta escapar os nomes das colunas e tabelas com [backtick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

```
SELECT `id`, `date` FROM `tabela`
```

Para mais detalhes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table

Também pode optar por usar uma nomenclatura diferente:

```
SELECT id, date_created FROM tabela
```

Por fim, cada um decide qual o padrão do seu próprio projeto.

## Convenção de nomes ([naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)))

Exemplo, para "Endereços de clientes" normalmente criaríamos uma tabela como "customer_address".

Padrões mais conhecidos:

- [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Exemplo: `CustomerAddress` ou `customerAddress`

- [Underscore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore).

As palavras são conectadas com uma underline/underscore. Exemplo: `customer_address`

- [Hifen](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%ADfen).

As palavras são conectadas com um hífen. Exemplo: `customer-address`

- [Uppercase / Lowercase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case).

Um padrão onde todas as letras são escritas em letras maísculas ou minúsculas.

Exemplo: `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS`, `CUSTOMERADDRESS`, `CUSTOMER-ADDRESS`, `customer_address`, `customeraddress`, `customer-address`

**Em relação ao name convention**, cada um escolhe o que gostar ou o que for mais conveniente. Particularmente, prefiro sempre o que for mais simples, portável, etc.

Um exemplo de dificuldade que pode ter na escolha de um padrão. O hífen, por exemplo, você pode pegar um sistema ou um host de hospedagem que não permite nomear com hífen as tabelas e nomes de colunas. Aí terá um problemão em adaptar os códigos e, como fará tudo na pressa, a gambiarra vai comer solta. rsrs

O uso de letra maiúscula também pode ter algum problema, mas normalmente é fácil de resolver. Um exemplo, com MySQL, temos a configuração [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names). É muito comum um inexperiente cair nesse problema. No ambiente de desenvolvimento cria um projeto onde o MySQL está com "lower_case_table_names" configurado como "case insensitive". E quando instala no servidor de produção (online), o hosting está com `lower_case_table_names` como "sensitive", o que começa a gerar diversos bugs no funcionamento do sistema. Se o bug correr de forma oculta, num processo onde não dispara erros, aí pode ter um problema grave caso envolva questão financeira e dados muito importantes.

Por essas e outras, particularmente prefiro um padrão simples e que funciona bem em linux, windows, mac, online, offline, enfim. O padrão é tudo em letra minúscula e palavras compostas separadas por underline. Isso é o suficiente para evitar um monte de problemas.

Vamos dar mais uma complicada?

Caso opte pelo CamelCase, como ficaria o padrão para nomes compostos com palavras que são abreviaturas e normalmente escritas em maiúsculo?

Exemplo: "HTTP Alguma Coisa". Ficaria assim

`HTTPAlgumaCoisa` ou `HttpAlgumaCoisa` ?

E se precisar de "XML HTTP Alguma Coisa"?

`XMLHTTPAlgumaCoisa`? ou `XmlHttpAlgumaCoisa` ?

E quando deparar-se com termos no plural?

enderecos ou endereco? cidade ou cidades? cliente ou clientes?

Por fim, são apenas observações básicas para que padronize o projeto desde o início. Assim evita perder tempo em ter que modificar a documentação com o projeto em andamento pois, pequenas pausas como essa vão consumindo o tempo, dispersando o foco no business model e, o prazo vai encurtando.

<sub>As estruturas dos exemplos são fictícias, com finalidade didática. O foco não é modelagem, mas sim a nomenclatura dentro do contexto da pergunta.</sub>

Comment: Muito bom, particularmente prefiro sem _underline_ `_`. Geralmente `id, name, addressid, created`

Comment: Excelente resposta! Estava justamente procurando isso. Em algumas leituras que fiz pela internet, alguns tópicos abordavam a questão de performance do BD quando usado nomes muito compridos, como os exemplos que você citou no caso de redundância. Sabe se isso realmente existe? Ou apenas "boato"?

Comment: O tamanho do nome não implica na performance significativamente. Claro que qualquer byte a mais é um custo de memória, mas é pequeno demais para dizer que deixa o DB lento. Claro que quanto menor o nome, melhor. Sempre procure criar nomes o menor possível. Aí tem que ser criativo e malabarista para conciliar a nomenclatura com o padrão do aplicativo.

Comment: @DanielOmine o que acha do meu quinhão, abaixo?

Comment: Não recomendo abreviações dessa forma, fica muito ruim a manutenção pois a documentação tem que ser consultada simplesmente para saber o nome de uma tabela, imagina os relacionamentos com vários níveis como ficaria isso. Sugiro nomes objetivos e, se possível, curtos, mas não abreviados: Exemplo: _"Contrato"_, _"ContratoItem"_. Bate o olho e já sabe do que se trata.

Comment: Que ótima resposta. Totalmente dentro do contexto. Sem fugir para outros tipos de argumentos. Show!

Answer (score 5):

Em nomenclaturas não existe certo ou errado. Em tese você pode fazer como desejar. Qualquer um que disser que é o certo ou o errado para isto estará sendo tendencioso.

Claro que existe alguns parâmetros reconhecidos que funcionam melhor. Mas que podem ser ignorados se tiver um bom motivo para isto. Sabe aqueles banco de dados que numeram todos os nomes? Eu totalmente contra isto, mas pode existir motivo para usá-lo. Hoje em dia, nenhum técnico, claro.

O importante é ser legível, algo que parece estar ciente da importância.

Se vai usar português ou inglês depende do projeto. Tem que fazer o que será útil para a equipe. Alias esse é um ponto importante, se mandarem você fazer de um jeito, até pode debater, tentar mostrar que algo não é o ideal, mas se não convencer, siga o que te mandam.

Se pode escolher, coloque nomes significativos. Tamanho não é um problema na maior parte dos casos, mas pode ser que alguma ferramente enrosque. Aí pode-se pensar se a ferramenta deveria ser usada, ela parece ser obsoleta ou mal pensada. Tamanho exagerado por se tornar um pouco chato pra usar, não só pra escrever (este até tem solução), mas pra ler também. Legibilidade é um conceito amplo, exagero pra um lado é tão ruim quanto para outro.

Existe um "erro" (não chega ser erro de fato, conforme já disse) clássico: usa o nome da tabela no nome da coluna. Pra que? Informação redundante é desnecessária. Algumas pessoas dizem que o `id` e eventualmente alguma outra coluna que depois será usada como chave estrangeira em outra tabela pode ter o nome da tabela para ficar igual ao da chave estrangeira que precisará o nome da tabela. Outras acham isto desnecessário, e de fato não costuma causar problema (a não ser que use alguma ferramenta que espera este padrão).

Se existir um motivo técnico para redundar os nomes, eu não faria isto. Eu também prefiro o uso de *pascalCase* do que usar *underline*, mas é gosto.

Algumas pessoas preferem usar nomes no plural ou até coletivos para nomes de tabelas. Há controvérsias quanto a isto.

Há até quem prefira um português mais fluente com preposições, artigos, etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quanto ao tamanho, realmente nunca me preocupei, a opção por fazer tudo em português é justamente pra facilitar pra equipe, particularmente, acho o inglês mais atraente, fica mais homogêneo com as demais linhas de código do projeto. Mas quanto a redundância eu preciso fingir que não vejo nada, por que em alguns casos, em consultas complexas ou com muitos `inner join` a redundância que eu causo ajuda na identificação das colunas de forma mais rápida e descarta o uso `alias` para nome das colunas, além de, também ajudar o compreendimento mais rápido do esquema.

Comment: A falta de redundância nunca me causou problema, afinal quando eu quiser eu uso o nome da tabela. Quando eu sou obrigado a usar o nome da tabela, ou quando ele é totalmente desnecessário para dar legibilidade, fica horrível ler aquilo redundante. Se gosta assim, faça assim, se me convidar pra trabalhar com você, eu recuso :)

Comment: Opá, obrigado pelos comentários @bigown. Eu estou na liderança do próximo projeto e estava pensando justamente nos *problemas* que eu teria em *implantar* essa forma de fazer as coisas. Acolho o seu comentário em forma de ação, vou perguntar aos outros da minha próxima equipe, se aceitam trabalhar dessa forma, e eu estarei mais aliviado em perguntar por isso, pelo menos vi que essa forma pode não ser errada e que possa que causar problemas, mas talvez um mau estar ;)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/incompletude/bancodedados

Escrevi uma documentação que tem por objetivo garantir boa experiência ao estabelecer regras de consistência em bancos de dados que atendem arquitetura RESTful, incluindo micro serviços. Há um workflow completo, com regras consistentes para desenvolvimento moderno, onde o objetivo é garantir a melhor experiência do usuário para desenvolvedores de todas as camadas. Suponho que essas premissas atendem também outras arquiteturas.

A tese é que a escolha dos nomes dos objetos no banco de dados é o processo mais importante do projeto, pois a pratica de repetir esses nomes em todas as camadas do desenvolvimento não é apenas encorajada, mas é um requisito.

Suponha por exemplo:

```
SELECT
    id_usuario,
    nome,
    senha,
    usuario,
    ativado,
    criado
FROM usuarios
WHERE
   usuario = 'Dev1' AND
   senha = 'Password1'
```

Sejam os objetos das linguagens de backend, os objetos Javascript, elementos HTML, a resposta JSON da API, ou até mesmo a URL, todos seguem o mesmo padrão:

```
GET /api/usuarios/1

<input type="text" id="nome" value="a">

for usuario in usuarios
   usuario.nome
   usuario.ativado

{ "usuarios": [{ "nome": "a", "ativado": true }, { "nome": "b", "ativado": false }]}
```

As razões são:

1. Facilita para o desenvolvedor. Não precisa aprender 2 dezenas de acrônimos complicados.
2. Facilita para o desenvolvedor. O tempo gasto no processo de escolher nomes é recuperado durante todo o desenvolvimento ao livrar-se da tarefa de inventar nomes coerentes para colunas como `fl_usr_atv`, que para uns vira `posicao`, para outros `status`, e para outros `flag`.
3. Facilita para o desenvolvedor. Se os nomes estão bem definidos, intuitivamente eles são utilizados no decorrer do projeto, gerando código mais consistente e simples de entender.
4. Facilita para o desenvolvedor. Desenvolvedores odeiam escolher nomes, então que tal fazer direito e uma vez só?
5. As IDEs são extremamente poderosas. O padrão `int_number` foi inventado para linguagens e IDEs de 3-4 décadas atrás, hoje para saber o tipo de uma variável basta passar o mouse sobre ela. Este padrão é usado paenas para casos especiais, como `id_usuario`.
6. Os transpilers são extremamente poderosos. As linguagens cospem qualquer objeto ou enumerável sem qualquer esforço, um objeto `javascript` vira `JSON` e `c#` no momento seguinte, de forma transparente, automática. Pra que atravancar o meio de campo com um banco de dados cheio de nomes e padrões complicados e esquisitos?
7. Essas regras derrubam hábitos criados por documentações antigas e em inglês mas que não fazem sentido em projetos modernos em português. Por exemplo, no inglês nomes de coletivo são preferíveis a plurais para nomes de tabela, `staff` é usado no lugar de `employees` porque `staff` esclarece melhor o conteúdo da tabela e gera código mais legível, `for employee in staff`. No entanto o português tem uma quantidade bastante limitada de nomes de coletivos, depois das tabelas `alcateia`, `colmeia` e `manada` não restam muitas outras. No singular, uma tabela chamada `usuario` convida o desenvolvedor a implementar o repositório `usuario`, daí pra `for linha in usuario` ou `for i in usuario` é um pulo. Terrível. A implementação aceitável é `for usuario in repositorioUsuario`, e a boa é `for usuario in usuarios`.
8. Essas regras são utilizadas em aplicações modernas em inglês, mas funcionam ainda melhor no português pois não há colisão de termos reservados do SQL, `order` vira `ordem`, por exemplo.
9. **Cria melhores produtos**. Compare as duas APIs abaixo, elas tem o mesmo objetivo.

https://cryptowat.ch/docs/api

https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-pricehistorical-