# Case sensitivo MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando que meu banco aceite letras maiusculas nos nomes da tableas, por exemplo no momento que crio a tabela

```
tbl_ALGUMACOISA
```

ela aparece para mim

```
tbl_algumacoisa
```

Assim também funciona com os campos, como devo fazer para solucionar estes problemas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No arquivo de configurações do MySQL, defina o o parâmetro `lower_case_table_names` com valor `2`.

Exemplo:

```
lower_case_table_names=2
```

<sub>Se não existe o parâmetro, acidione-o.</sub>

Spós as alterações, salve o arquivo e reinicie o MySQL.

**O arquivo de configurações padrão**

Windows: my.ini

Linux: my.cnf

O local varia conforme a instalação.

Salientando que esses são os nomes padrão. O nome do arquivo pode ser diferente ou pode estar carregando um arquivo específico em tempo de execução.

Adicionalmente, recomendo ler esse post: [Nomenclatura de tabela e coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138452/nomenclatura-de-tabela-e-coluna/138528#138528)

Comment: meu arquivo não tem esta váriavel, estou taralhando com xammp para gerir meu banco de dados.

Comment: Se não existe o parâmetro, acidione-o, salve o arquivo e reinicie o MySQL.

Comment: nAO FUNCIONOU PARA O NOME DO BANCO

Comment: O nOmE dO pArÂmEtRo É lower_case_TABLE_NAMES. pOr DeDuÇãO, é PaRa TaBeLaS e CoLuNaS. o NoMe Da BaSe De DaDoS dEvE sEr Em LeTrAs MiNúScUlAs