# É certo identificar as colunas das tabelas do banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou com uma dúvida: Em grandes projetos, que exigem muita relação entre as tabelas, muitos JOINs, identificar cada coluna com a tabela, por exemplo:

Ao invés de:

**Nome da tabela:** users

id   |   name   | email

Assim:

user_id |   user_name   | user_email

Visto que terão outras tabelas com o mesmo tipo de dado, como name, email e principalmente ID. Tem problema em não identificar? Atrapalha nos JOINs? Como grandes empresas com Facebook fazem?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse tópico que criei pouco tempo atrás, as respostas foram incríveis por si só. [Nomenclatura de tabela e coluna](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138452/nomenclatura-de-tabela-e-coluna)

Comment: Nossa, não tinha visto, está realmente muito bom. O que faço agora? Removo essa pergunta?

Comment: Já li tudo, mas queria saber se tem problema com conflito usando vários JOINs, o que não foi explicado lá.

Comment: Era justamente isso um dos pontos que eu levantei mas pouco expliquei lá. Um exemplo, tenho a tabela usuário com o campo `id` e a tabela `acesso` com o mesmo campo `id`, se no meu `select` eu não dizer que o campo `id` do usuário se torne `usuario_id`, aí ele irá devolver uma única coluna `id`(que pode ser do usuário ou do acesso) e aí é um probleminha. Nesse caso, para evitar os possíveis conflitos eu tomo cuidado com isso que citei acima e uso muito bem o `alias`, como solução.

Comment: Sempre usar alias então? Mas e se tenho muitos campos, como falei, um projeto grande, com várias colunas com o mesmo nome, o alias seria uma boa solução? Não seria gambiarroso?

Comment: Nossa, você é minha alma gêmea, eu já pensei em tudo que tá questionando rsrs. Mas então, eu acho que recurso foi inventado pra ser usado, se não for usado não tem sentido. Manda bala em `alias` tanto quanto `inner join`, são recursos, tão aí pra ser usados.