# Esse tipo de Normalizaçao é viavel?

Tags: mysql, sql, normalização

[image: É viável fazer esse tipo de normalizaçao?]

Daqui terá mais outras tabelas onde a pessoa se classificará como, proprietário, cliente, fornecedor, entre outros.
Minha dúvida é, eu separando uma tabela para cpf e outra para cnpj da tabela pessoa, é bom?
No meu pensamento, com essa normalizaçao não haverá campos em branco de cpf e nem campos em branco de cnpj.

Comment: Posso estar equivocado, mas a não ser que você vincule outras informações na tabela de cpf, ou na de cnpj, que seria mais conveniente, tipo informações do estabelecimento, essa "normalização" é desnecessária...

Comment: O que seria viável? Tem algum parâmetro para estabelecer isso? Apesar de curta já tem coisa estranha. Essa coisa de ter uma tabela para cada tipo de entidade é uma coisa tão antiga...

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro algo modular, evitando atrelar a estrutura a regras de negócios localizadas.

Como exemplo, eu não criaria 2 tabelas, uma para CPF e outra para CNPJ, mesmo que fosse um sistema localizado. Sugiro algo genérico:

```
person
    id (unique)
    date_created
    date_updated
    other_column1
    other_column2

person_document
    id (unique)
    date_created
    date_updated
    person_id (relacionado com person.id)
    document_id (relacionado com document.id)
    data char(50)

document
    id (unique)
    date_created
    date_updated
    country_id (relacionado com country.id)
    title (nome do documento)

country
    id (unique)
    date_created
    date_updated
    title (nome do país)
```

Muitos programadores pensam que quando tem muitas tabelas o sistema é mais complexo, complicado, pesado, etc. Mas isso não são bons argumentos porque não influencia na performance de forma relevante. Para compreender, segue leittura abaixo.

Quando se está fazendo um sistema pequeno no qual tem certeza que jamais utilizará para algo maior e principalmente internacional, não tem muito sentido montar toda essa estrutura. Mas de qualquer forma é uma estrutura que funciona bem num projeto pequeno e local quanto num projeto grande ou internacionalizado. Então, por quê não normalizar dentro de um padrão flexível que serve para ambos os casos ao invés de criar algo "engessado" que não será reaproveitável?

Esse é um dos motivos de existir a normalização.

Explicando melhor a estrutura acima.

Temos a tabela de pessoas (**person**). Nessa tabela não há nenhuma informação sobre quais documentos a pessoa possui. Na tabela **documents**, é onde os documentos são cadastrados, porém, sem ainda vincular com a tabela de **person**. Nessa tabela, serão cadastrados todos os documentos exigidos pelo modelo de negócio.

O importante aqui é não atrelar a estrutura ao modelo de negócio, ou seja, evitar que seja algo localizado.

Nessa tabela de documentos, os diversos tipos de documentos serão cadastrados. CPF, CNPJ, RG, Carteira de Motorista, Passaporte, etc.

A tabela **person_document** é onde são feitos os relacionamentos. Nessa tabela, apenas será cadastrado o número ou o código serial do documento. O que identifica qual é o documento, é a coluna `document.id`.

A coluna `data` é to tipo `char(50)` pois nem todos os documentos são numéricos. Há muitos tipos de documentos que incluem caracteres alfanuméricos. Por isso o tipo CHAR é mais adequado.

Importante também observar que a tabela documents é relacionada com a tabela country. Isso torna possível usar o sistema para um modelo de negócios onde exige-se saber o país de origem do documento independente da nacionalidade da pessoa.

Isso é apenas uma forma resumida. Claro que é possível melhorar, fazer alguns ajustes, etc. Mas não quer dizer que deve fazer dessa forma e tampouco tem essa pretensão em ser a solução definitiva.

Com essa estrutura genérica, o sistema torna-se mais flexível e portável. Pode aproveitar o mesmo sistema para uso em qualquer país sem precisar modificar a estrutura. Do contrário, se fizer algo atrelado as regras locais, por exemplo, com colunas ou tabelas específicas para CPF, essas tabelas ou colunas serão inúteis para outros países e muitas vezes inútil até mesmo dentro do Brasil para casos de cadastro de menor de idade, imigrantes, turistas, refugiados, indocumentados, residentes temporários, etc.

Pode parecer um pouco estranho a tabela `country` relacionada com `document`, pois poderia relacionar `country` com `person`, certo? O problema nisso é engessar o sistema desconsiderando pessoas com múltiplas nacionalidades ou mesmo que não tenha nem mesmo dupla nacionalidade, pode ter documentos de outros países.

Note também que em todas as tabelas do exemplo adicionei as colunas `date_created` e `date_updated`. Muitos sistemas seguem isso como padrão. Sempre possuir uma coluna que informe data e hora em que foi registrado e atualizado.

Isso é um assunto que desvia um pouco do assunto, pois é relacionado a log de atividades e otimização. Se preferir, pode ignorar.

Na tabela original da pergunta `tb_pessoa`, existe uma coluna `pessoa_tipo`. Isso é também um jeito de "engessar" a estrutura. Para algo mais flexível, o ideal seria uma outra tabela para definir o tipo da pessoa. Preferi não comentar pois se tornaria algo repetitivo por seguir a mesma lógica apresentada na estrutura proposta. E assim segue para quaisquer outras colunas ou tabelas que possam tornar o sistema (engessado) localizado.

## Precisa mesmo de tanta coisa? Mesmo num projeto pequeno?

Aqui voltamos a falar sobre se isso tudo é realmente necessário. Se você quer apenas construir um sistema de controle de caixa de um barzinho do zé da esquina numa periferia de uma cidadezinha do interior que não tem mais que 5 mil habitantes, por quê complicar com isso tudo?

Pois repito novamente o que foi comentado alguns parágrafos acima que, essa estrutura serve tanto para um projeto pequeno quanto para um projeto grande. Pode existir uma diferença na performance porém é irrelevante. Afinal, num projeto pequeno não haverá um fluxo grande. Portanto, a preocupação com performance é irrelevante. Num projeto maior exigirá muito mais do que isso para obter uma boa performance.

O ponto chave aqui é portabilidade. Poderá usar a mesma estrutura para modelos de negócios diversificados.

<sub>obs: Os exemplos acima são meramente didáticos.</sub>

Sobre nomenclatura, veja esse link: [Nomenclatura de tabela e coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138452/nomenclatura-de-tabela-e-coluna/138528#138528)

Answer (score 0):

Bom como eu não posso comentar, eu faria tudo na mesma tabela e ainda faria um unique para garantir unicidade, melhor manutenção, um exemplo meu:

```
customer{
  id integer
  document varchar,
  document_type varchar,
  ...
  unique(document, document_type)
}
```

Alem disso, desta forma eu estou me garantindo que se em algum outro momento meu cliente passar aceitar algum outro documento sabe-se lá por que, não preciso criar mais uma tabela, mais uma coisas para dor de cabeça.

Bom isso é uma preferência minha, mas vai como dica: Colocar prefixo no campo dentro de uma tabela, se é `tb_pessoa`, não precisa ser `pessoa_id`, só `id` é o suficiente, pois se algum momento for fazer um inner que precisa de junção `tb_pessoa.pessoa_id` já facilita `tb_pessoa.id` e nem preciso dizer também do `tb_`.

Saiu um pouco fora, mas espero ter lhe auxiliado com o assunto principal.

Comment: Eu no caso iria preferir manter `id_nome_da_tabela`.
Na hora de fazer vários `inner join`, pode ate ser mais custoso, porém fica fácil saber de que tabela vem o `id`, e consequentemente, `fk`, e em futuras engenharias reversas fica fácil a manutenção

Comment: [disclaimer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs0Tq.jpg)

Comment: Bom eu pelo menos uso algo assim `customers.id` me da a mesma visão e organização citada, mas claro, isso é muito uma questão de gosto, inclusive até irei colocar um adendo na minha resposta.